# How to Have Multiple Python GUIs Running at the Same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you run two python GUI windows at the same time in python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tow main types of windows -- modal and non-modal.

You cannot interact with two modal windows at the same time.

Depending on your GUI framework there are different ways how to have opened two non-modal windows.

If you are using PyQt4, google for modeless dialogs to see examples of how to use them.

Otherwise give more details of what are you trying to achieve.